# counting upper case letters in recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

i know this is wrong, however just learning how to do recursive functions and trying to understand how to work this out better.

```
    #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;


    int getUpper ( const string& s, int high) {

      int count=0;


       if(s.size()>0) {

         if (s[0] <='Z' && s[0] >='A') 
          count++;

       return getUpper(s.substr(1,s.size()-1), high-1);

    }
     return count;
 }

     int getUpper (const string& s){
         int high=s.size()-1;

        int count=getUpper(s,high);
      return count;
   }


   int main()
  {
     string s="WeLC";
    int value=getUpper(s);
    cout << value;
      return 0;
  }
```

Why is this not returning the count number? of 4.

Comment: As a side note, `std::count_if` is the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One hint: `getUpper` returns the value without incorporating the `count`.

```
return getUpper(s.substr(1,s.size()-1), high-1); // no `count`
```

BTW, `getUpper("WeLC")` should return `3`, not `4`.

Answer (score 0):

Realize that each recursive invocation of `getUpper` has its own copy of the local variable `count`. `count++` doesn't do anything useful as the variable isn't actually used for anything after the increment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem s when u call each tym your function count is initialized so ultimately it will be 0 at the last tym it called.So better solution is have count as global var.For E.g

```
int count1=0;
```

int getUpper ( const string& s, int high) {

int count=0;
       if(s.size()>0) {

```
     if (s[0] <='Z' && s[0] >='A')
      count++;
     count1++;

   return getUpper(s.substr(1,s.size()-1), high-1);

}
 return count1;
```

}

Now count1 will give the result.